# Joomla 2.5 Back-end Add custom Field using jquery and JFormField

Tags: joomla, module

I have fetched a problem to developing joomla(2.5) module. I have xml file which has custom field type addlocation.

```
<fieldset name="addLocations" label="Add Locations" addfieldpath="/modules    /mod_pr_weather/elements">
    <field type="addlocation" name="locations"></field>
</fieldset>
```

and has addlocation.php file,

```
<?php

defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;

jimport('joomla.form.formfield');

class JFormFieldAddlocation extends JFormField {
protected $type = 'Addlocations';
protected function getInput() {

$addFrom = '<div id="pr_maindiv">  <h1>'.JText::_('MOD_PR_WEATHER_HEADER_ADD_LOCATION').'</h1>'.$this->getForm("single").'</div>';
    $addFromBlock = '<div id="pr_maindiv_b" style="clear:both;"><h1>'.JText::_('MOD_PR_WEATHER_HEADER_ADD_LOCATION').'</h1>'.$this->getForm("multi").'</div>';

    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();

    $doc->addScriptDeclaration('

            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                     jQuery("#pr_maindiv_b").css("display","none");
                    jQuery("#jform_params_slideshow_style").change(function(){
                            if(jQuery(this).val()==2){
                              jQuery("#pr_maindiv").css("display","none");
                            jQuery("#pr_maindiv_b").css("display","block");
                                }else{
                                jQuery("#pr_maindiv").css("display","block");
                                jQuery("#pr_maindiv_b").css("display","none");
                                }
                        });

                });

            ');
    return $addFrom . $addFromBlock;
}

private function getForm($type = 'single') {
    $form_type_tooltip =  'class="hasTip" title="' . JText::_('MOD_PR_WEATHER_ADDLOCATION_TOOLTIP') . '"';
    $from='';   
        if ($type=='single') {
            $from = '<p><label'.$form_type_tooltip.'>'.JText::_('MOD_PR_WEATHER_ADDLOCATION_LABEL').'</label></p><p><input type="text" value="GEOLOCATION" placeholder="GEOLOCATION" name="single_location"/></p>
                     <p><input type="button" id="addMore" value="more"></p>';
        }else{

            $from = '<div style="clear:both;" id="first"><h3>Frist Block</h3><p><label'.$form_type_tooltip.'>'.JText::_('MOD_PR_WEATHER_ADDLOCATION_LABEL').'</label></p><p><input type="text" value="GEOLOCATION" placeholder="GEOLOCATION" name="first_block_loc"/></p>
                     <p><input type="button" id="addMoreFrist" value="more"></p></div>';
            $from .= '<div style="clear:both;" id="second"><h3>Second Block</h3><p><label'.$form_type_tooltip.'>'.JText::_('MOD_PR_WEATHER_ADDLOCATION_LABEL').'</label></p><p><input type="text" value="GEOLOCATION" placeholder="GEOLOCATION" name="second_block_loc"/></p>
                     <p><input type="button" id="addMoreSecond" value="more"></p></div>';
            $from .= '<div style="clear:both;" id="third"><h3>Third Block</h3><p><label'.$form_type_tooltip.'>'.JText::_('MOD_PR_WEATHER_ADDLOCATION_LABEL').'</label></p><p><input type="text" value="GEOLOCATION" placeholder="GEOLOCATION" name="third_block_loc"/></p>
                     <p><input type="button" id="addMoreThird" value="more"></p></div>';
            $from .= '<div style="clear:both;" id="fourth"><h3>Fourth Block</h3><p><label'.$form_type_tooltip.'>'.JText::_('MOD_PR_WEATHER_ADDLOCATION_LABEL').'</label></p><p><input type="text" value="GEOLOCATION" placeholder="GEOLOCATION" name="fourth_block_loc"/></p>
                     <p><input type="button" id="addMoreFourth" value="more"></p></div>';
        }
        return $from;
}
}
```

And js file for button type triggering:

```
jQuery("#addMore").click(function(){
jQuery("#pr_maindiv").append("<p style='clear:both;'><input type='text'       value='GEOLOCATION' placeholder='GEOLOCATION' name='single_location[]'/></p>");
});
jQuery("#addMoreFrist").click(function(){
jQuery("div#first").append("<p style='clear:both;'><input type='text'         value='GEOLOCATION' placeholder='GEOLOCATION' name='first_block_loc[]'/></p>");
});
jQuery("#addMoreSecond").click(function(){
jQuery("div#second").append("<p style='clear:both;'><input type='text'     value='GEOLOCATION' placeholder='GEOLOCATION' name='second_block_loc[]'/></p>");
});
jQuery("#addMoreThird").click(function(){
jQuery("div#third").append("<p style='clear:both;'><input type='text'     value='GEOLOCATION' placeholder='GEOLOCATION' name='third_block_loc[]'/></p>");
});
jQuery("#addMoreFourth").click(function(){
jQuery("div#fourth").append("<p style='clear:both;'><input type='text'     value='GEOLOCATION' placeholder='GEOLOCATION' name='fourth_block_loc[]'/></p>");
});
```

When button type click event occur, perfectly append into back-end form. But when save click, every xml field type value saved, but custom fields types do not saved into database params column. WHY? If my question is not clear, then please inform me to upload full file. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla will only store results coming from an input field with the name you provide in your xml definition: thus your jquery should bind to change or forms' submit and concat / join the values you add and store those in a field named "location".  Onload, you should have the reverse i.e. populating custom fields based on the value of location (this can be achieved easily with php).

Comment: thanks for advanced. would you please kind enough to give me a tutorials. (please not joomla docs, because, i want add more option. click add_more increases number of input fields in back-end form).

Answer (score 0):

If you will set the field  name as    **name="jform[first_block_loc]"**   in the addlocation.php while defining the fields then it must store the value in the params column..